# VB.NET Web application Import/inheritance/withevents problems?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, import, handles

I've inherited this VB web application.I'm trying to build the project file and expect that it will eventually compile but right now it has a few pages that come up with wierd things like "Import Classxxx not found" even though I can go to it via the "go to definition" and it finds it and it has public methods and other pages in the same folder have no problem with the import at all. Some problem with inheritance. Some pages work 100% and a few have this can't find problem on the exact same class. The failing pages also say they need "withevents" on the handlers but the other pages, in the same folder, have no problems with the exact same handlers?

There are no "Namespaces" that I can see in this application. None of the classes have namespace wrappers. Not that that matters cause again 99% of the pages are just fine. I have copied the test of the page to notepad and replaced it back just in case there were any stray characters but no effect.

There are apx.vb files.

Has any one seen this kind of problem.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently this is a VS Web site not an application? Don't remember that... Any comments on converting it?

Comment: Right-click project and convert to application.

Answer (score 0):

Weird stuff like that - check for presence of other files (*.aspx.vb) on the file-system, that are not in your project.  They can stuff things up, big time, and you get weird errors like that.  Failing that, can you post code segments that are giving the errors/warnings etc?